# How can I return the Lucene score of my query when using the Neo4J REST server?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I have been able to use the Lucene query syntax so far.  Now I need to be able to return the scores and number of hits on nodes by modifying my query line:

GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/myIndex?query=myKey:myValue

In other words, I do not want to have to create an embedded graph database because I am trying to access the data I have saved in my REST server.  Any suggestions on how to return the score and hits?

Could I perhaps create an instance of a class that Lucene offers to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

to do this, you will probably have to write a small scoring Neo4j Server unmanaged extension, since this is outside the core REST API, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-unmanaged-extensions.html for details. As parameters you could take the index, and the scoring parameters and the query.

Would that help?

/peter